# Hyperledger REST Server and Angular App - Could Not Find API Route

Tags: angular-cli, webpack-dev-server, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am following the tutorial [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/ultimate-end-to-end-tutorial-to-create-an-application-on-blockchain-using-hyperledger-3a83a80cbc71) and [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial). I have a REST API and Angular Web App set up on a VirtualBox Ubuntu 16.04.04 Virtual Machine and can access them from localhost:3000 and localhost:4200 within the VM, respectively.

From http://localhost:4200, 
I was getting 
`Error: Could not connect to REST server. Please check your configuration details`

So, in the `my-app/src/app/configuration.ts` file, I edited the ApiIP to be my VM IP:

```
public ApiIP: string = "http://10.0.2.15";
```

Now, the current error is:

> Error: 404 - Could not find API route. Please check your available
>   APIs.

So this question is unanswered here: 
[Hyperledger REST Server Angular Web App getting could not connect to REST server outside localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563282/hyperledger-rest-server-angular-web-app-getting-could-not-connect-to-rest-server)
, so excuse me, I'm not looking to be redundant, but my case may be different, so I decided to open a thread.

I have also tried changing start to `"start": "ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 -port 4200",` in the package.json file.

Your help would be invaluable, thanks guys!

Comment: Is your REST server running?  You could consider starting it separately from the Angular app.  What version of Composer are you running?

Comment: Thanks! Currently, it's v0.19.1. I've updated it from v0.19.0. The rest server was running fine, and I was able to POST and GET with a 200 Response code.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262477/deploying-an-angular-application-in-hyperledger-composer/47262761#47262761 including instruction on package.json if required